# ng2 dynamic forms custom async validation on DynamicFormGroupModel

Tags: angular, validation, dynamic-forms

I am using `ng2-dynamic-forms` and I can't understand how `asyncvalidation` works with dynamic form group Models.

I couldn't find an example with `asyncvalidator` as **Property** of `DynamicFormControlModel` (see:[asyncValidator api doc](http://ng2-dynamic-forms.udos86.de/docs/classes/_core_src_model_form_group_dynamic_form_group_model_.dynamicformgroupmodel.html#asyncvalidator))

The ultimate goal is to make an `asyncvalidator to check area input values of **areasGroup** and check if subArea is **smaller** than **mainArea**

I have done this [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/gAuEzUfW7XwoRxhEYPQt/) to test `asyncvalidation` but it doesn't work.

Can you help me?

Comment: You can start with this https://plnkr.co/edit/Tgl98NGnAFwYovoOwCan?p=preview Try editing `sub area input`

Comment: Thank's VERY MUCH
Thanks to your help, I managed to understand asyncvalidation property and now I can continue with the application I'm trying to make for the forest service
I correct my [plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/gAuEzUfW7XwoRxhEYPQt/) and now works fine. !!!
Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear i helped

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to [Avnesh Shakya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2042251/avnesh-shakya) i find answer:
At DynamicFormGroupModel properties we must set:

```
asyncValidator : {areaGroupValidator:areaGroupValidator}
```

and at areaGroupValidator function we must return function like:

```
export function areaGroupValidator() {
return function(formGroup: FormGroup): Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
  let TotalArea = formGroup.controls.areaInput.value;
  let SubArea = formGroup.controls.subAreaInput.value
  if (SubArea > TotalArea) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve({areaGroupValidator: true});
    }); 
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(null);
    });
  }
```

}